# Java regexp for textfield matching

Tags: java, regex, textfield

So I'm working with Java regexp and I'm having a bit of troubles to create one. I must get a regexp that matches numbers between 0.0 and 359.9 with always exactly one decimal, which isn't super complicated, but I'm doing a regexp for a textfield meaning that if the expression doesn't match at ever character, I can't type further.

What it means is that basically 3 35 359 359. 359.9 must all match for me to type in the field.

I've been trying stuff around with `\d(\.\d)?` but that doesn't match every step of the way and `\d(\.)?(\d)?` allows it to start with a zero. I can't get really further with what I know of regexp and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:3[0-5]\d|[12]\d{2}|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d?)?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mW0lI5/3

Comment: This allows the expression to start with a 0, but it's good enough for what I'm doing, thanks !

Comment: I did that deliberately assuming this should be acceptable. But this can be easily fixed by changing the `[0-2]` range to `[12]`. Amended the answer.

Comment: `\d{1,2}` will still match 01.0. And replacing it with `[1-9]\d` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Simpe regex.It may work as you required

```
 ^\d[0-5]?[0-9]?(\.)?([0-9])?$
```